# Разделение List с большим количеством объектов на другие листы

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Хотелось бы узнать, какие есть оптимальные способы разбиения листа на более мелкие листы по значениям в обьекте, желательно в рамках Java SE**7**.
Например есть ArrayList personList содержащий 1000 обьектов типа Person, отсортированный по Person.name. Нужно разбить personList, на другие листы по одинаковым именам персон. Пока кроме подобных вещей, ничего в голову не пришло:

```
ArrayList<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Person>> allLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Person>>();
    ArrayList<Person> arr2 = new ArrayList<Person>();
    String name = personList.get(0).getName();
    arr2.add(personList.get(0));
    for (int i = 1; i < personList.size(); i++) {
        if(!name.equals(personList.get(i).getName())) {
            name = personList.get(i).getName();
            allLists.add(arr2);
            arr2 = new ArrayList<Person>();
        }
        if(personList.size() == i+1) {
            arr2.add(personList.get(i));
            allLists.add(arr2);
            break;
        }
        arr2.add(personList.get(i));
    }
```

Comment: через стримы сделай

Comment: а если много данных, то через parallelstream

Comment: @Санаев Они доступны в 8й версии jdk, забыл указать,что мне нужны варианты решений до 7й версии.

Comment: я как понял у тебя есть слово - разделитель и ты по нему разделяешь лист?

Comment: можно попробовать через sublist сделать

Comment: @Санаев Допустим есть лист {Алексей,Алексей,Алексей,Андрей,Андрей,Борис}, нужно разбить на одинаковые имена: {Алексей,Алексей,Алексей}, {Андрей,Андрей}, {Борис}. Так как, подобных данных много, интересно узнать, какой способ менее затратный.

Comment: это легко делается через collect , жаль, что нельзя использовать java 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Если требуется разбить list на одинаковые элементы:**

```
 List<String> personList = new ArrayList<>();
        personList.add("Dimon");
        personList.add("Dimon");
        personList.add("Dimon");
        personList.add("Ivan");
        personList.add("Ivan");
        personList.add("Ivan");
        personList.add("Petr");
        personList.add("Petr");
        personList.add("Petr");
        personList.add("Max");
        personList.add("Sergey");
        personList.add("Leha");
        personList.add("Leha");
        personList.add("Leha");
        personList.add("Max");
        personList.add("Leha");
        personList.add("Leha");
        personList.add("Leha");
        List<List<String>> allLists = new ArrayList<>();
        int k=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < personList.size()-1; i++) {
            String name = personList.get(i++);
            while(i< personList.size() && name.equals(personList.get(i)) ){i++;}
            if(i< personList.size()){
                allLists.add(personList.subList(k,i));
                k=i--;
            }
        }
        allLists.add(personList.subList(k,personList.size()));
```

**Результат такой:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Здесь `k` - это начало индекса **подлиста**.

Далее после того, как мы нашли имя **`name`** (**name** - это слово - разделитель) мы делаем **sublist** по **i+1**(не включительно) и записываем результат в лист.

```
List<String> personList = new ArrayList<>();
      personList.add("Dimon");
    personList.add("Ivan");
    personList.add("Petr");
    personList.add("Max");
    personList.add("Sergey");
    personList.add("Leha");
    personList.add("Max");
    personList.add("Leha");
    List<List<String>> allLists = new ArrayList<>();
    String name = "Max";
    int k=0;
    for (int i = 1; i < personList.size(); i++) {
        if(name.equals(personList.get(i))) {
            allLists.add(personList.subList(k,i+1));
            k=i+1;
        }
    }
    allLists.add(personList.subList(k,personList.size()));
```

**Ниже результат функции:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]